# IF statement Panda Dataframe: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ambiguous

I have a dataframe with only float data. I basically want to create a new column that will get the value from another column if it satisfies a condition and the value of another column if it doesn't.
All my columns are of float type.

```
for col in list_scenarios:
    df_merged['in_scenario_'+ col] = 1.0
    print(df_merged['in_scenario_' + col])
    if df_merged[col].shift(1)== 1.0:
        df_merged['in_scenario_' + col] = df_merged['in_scenario_'+ col].shift(1)*df_merged[asset +'_r']
    else:
        df_merged['in_scenario_' + col] = df_merged['in_scenario_'+ col].shift(1)
    print(df_merged['in_scenario_' + col])
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Main/PycharmProjects/Macrobond_API/scenario testing.py", line 268, in <module>
    if df_merged[col].shift(1)== 1.0:
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1121, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

i can't figure out what's ambiguous.

Thanks

```
My dataframe looks like this (month year are indices)
            sp500_500  USA  MEXICO  sp500_500_r
month year                                                           
6     2017   2423.41  1.0      1.0     0.004814
7     2017   2470.30  1.0      1.0     0.019349
8     2017   2471.65  1.0      1.0     0.000546
```

Comment: Why don't you use a nested `np.where`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way around it.

```
for col in list_scenarios:
    df_merged['in_scenario_'+ col] = df_merged[asset +'_r']
    df_merged[col] = df_merged[col].shift(1)
    df_merged.loc[df_merged[col] ==0, 'in_scenario_'+ col] = 0
```

This gives me the 'returns' I wanted. Then I just need to build the index from this returns starting with 1 as the first value.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`df_merged[col].shift(1)== 1.0` you compare two different types
`df_merged[col].shift(1)` return a dataframe. If you want to get first value of that column you could use iloc. `df_merged[col].iloc[0] == 1.0`

```
a
   x  
0   0   
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
4   4   

a.x.shift(1)

   x  
0   NaN   
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
4   4  

a.x.iloc[0]

1
```

Comment: The things is I am always looking for the relative and not absolute position.

Comment: @RomM you could change it. what thing it depend on?

Comment: It is basically to iterate through each  row. Take the value before or after in a column to make operations on another column. I am kind of used to it with STATA but not with python.